# AngularJS: server call on tab/browser close

Tags: angularjs

I have a section in my application where I establish a communication between the server and the client that loops forever until the user leaves this screen. When the user leaves the screen, I detect this issue with `$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart')` and send a $http call to stop the process in the server.

I want to perform that same $http when the user closes the current tab or browser but I cannot get this done.

First of all this is the service function that makes the $http call:

```
function cancelCommProcess(webId, commActionId) {
          return $http.get(BASE_URL + '/rest/comm/kill-current-com-process/' + webId + '/' + commActionId)
            .then(
                    function(response) {
                        return response;
                    }
            );
      }
```

As I said, when I call this function in the `$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart')` or some other point, it works.

Now I have the following code to call this function when tab/browser is closed:

```
$window.onbeforeunload = function (evt) {
            if ($rootScope.CMC_ACTION_IDENTIFIER.CMC_ACTION_MONITORING === currentCommActionId) {
                CMCService.cancelCommProcess(currentWebId, currentCommActionId)
                    .then(
                            function() {
                                console.log('HELLO');
                            }
                    );
            }
        }
```

This way the $http call doesn't reach the server, but if I simply made the next change, then it works:

```
$window.onbeforeunload = function (evt) {
            if ($rootScope.CMC_ACTION_IDENTIFIER.CMC_ACTION_MONITORING === currentCommActionId) {
                CMCService.cancelCommProcess(currentWebId, currentCommActionId)
                    .then(
                            function() {
                                myTest();
                            }
                    );
            }
        }

        function myTest() {
            console.log('HELLO');
        }
```

Even more, previous method works in Chrome and Firefox but not in Edge. But it works (I mean, the $http call reaches the server) if I do it like this:

```
$window.onbeforeunload = function (evt) {
    if ($rootScope.CMC_ACTION_IDENTIFIER.CMC_ACTION_MONITORING === currentCommActionId) {
        CMCService.cancelCommProcess(currentWebId, currentCommActionId)
            .then(
                    function() {
                        myTest();
                        //console.log('HELLO');
                    }
            );
    }
    return "";
}

function myTest() {
    console.log('HELLO');
}
```

Of course I get the confirm message to leave or stay the page, but I don't know why the call reaches the server just by showing this message.

I don't really understand how this works so I appreciate your help. The idea of the $http call is to tell the server to interrupt the current communication process but I feel this method is not truthful.

Would you help me to figure out what's the best approach for this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use socket.io that keep connection alive between client and server and not loop in server.

This event fire when controller destory you can use it

```
$scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
   console.log("destory");
});
```

Comment: This is not triggered when tab/browser is closed.